# Get a table from R environment into .md format with dput

Tags: r, markdown

I am creating several outputs that I would like to include in a .md. I am not in control of chosing the .md format (so I cannot transform it into a Rmd, it would maybe be a problem with my collaborators).

Is there a way, similar to `dput()`, to get a dataframe directly formated in .md?

```
# my data frame
df <- structure(list(year_yyyy = c(2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009), `01` = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), `02` = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), `03` = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)) 

# getting an object I can copy paste to another Rmd document/another session easily
dput(df)
```

Desired output of the function `dmd()` that would get me an output ready to be pasted into a .md:

```
# dmd(df)
# 
# # Which would give
# year_yyyy  |01 |02  |03
# -----------|---|----|---
# 2005       |2  |2   |2    
# 2006       |2  |2   |2   
# 2007       |2  |2   |2    
# 2008       |2  |2   |2
```

And once in a md, it would look like a table: [image: table]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can tell `rmarkdown::render` not to delete the .md file it creates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kable()` from package `knitr` seems to do what you want:

```
knitr::kable(df, format="pipe")


#| year_yyyy| 01| 02| 03|
#|---------:|--:|--:|--:|
#|      2005|  2|  2|  2|
#|      2006|  2|  2|  2|
#|      2007|  2|  2|  2|
#|      2008|  2|  2|  2|
#|      2009|  2|  2|  3|
```

The `align` argument might need to be specified if you want to get exactly the same format as in your example.